# How do Power and Strength values correlate?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, emission

When creating a non-light and giving it an emission shader, what values of "Strength" are equivalent to given values of "Power" in an area light?

*Not* a duplicate of [Understanding light power values](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149304/understanding-light-power-values). This isn't talking about options in lights, but options in emission shaders that aren't lights on their own.

Comment: Related: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/cycles-unit-of-light-energy-attn-brecht/12456

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some testing. You can use this as a reference sheet :).

> *Power : Strength* ratio is *10:2,5* (for 1m² area)

- *Area lights* use *Power* (W), *Mesh lights* use *Strength*
- Mesh light used - default plane with *Emission* shader

---

**Intensity and size relationship**

- *Area lights* - *maintain* their intensity with increased size.
- *Mesh lights* - *increase* their intensity with increased size

[image]

**Power:Strength reference sheet**

- I tested these as 4096x4096 images and still couldn't tell the difference.
- Sorry for the color banding and compression artifacts.
- Noise is a *tiny bit* higher for *Mesh lights*.

[image][image]
[image][image]
[image][image]

---

[image]