# Is there a way to see the lumens (or watt) emission value from a surface?

Tags: rendering, light

I would like to know some precise illumination values from a combination of light sources, so I am looking for a way to view the lumens values from a surface (for example a flat plane). Is there a way to do this?

Best I can do so far is:

- Using the `Raw` View Transform in `Color Management`, using Right Click in the render window, I get values of HSL Luminance that might correspond to lumens (?)
- Using the `False Color` View Transform in `Color Management` I can see the exposure as a heat map. Ideally I would be able to get the underlying numerical values.

Comment: Hello :). Interesting thread on Blenderartists.org: [Cycles, unit of light energy ATTN: Brecht](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/cycles-unit-of-light-energy-attn-brecht/12456)

Comment: And a related Q&A here: [Simulating a 40W Light Bulb](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/180507/78972)