# Realistic deep water shader

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders

How would you go about creating a realistic deep water shader to depict a scene such as this one from blue planet II? I tried with a volume scatterer but had mixed results. Ideally it would be amazing to tie the shader to the water's depth, thus simulating everything from shallow waters, twilight zone, and the deep.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). This is practically just dense volumetrics. *Principled Volume* is all you need. Unfortunately, Cycles isn't very good at rendering volumetrics, so you'll get *a lot* of noise.

Comment: Thanks! Any advice on how to increase the rendering's quality?

Comment: Hey :). High samples with a Denoiser, there's no magic button. Last time I rendered such a scene I used 15 000+ samples.

Comment: Or you could use Eevee, but you'll need to render at double resolution to get it pixel perfect. Unfortunately, Eevee is also more finicky than Cycles.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All you need is the *Principled Volume shader*.

1. Create a volumetric cube
2. Give the volume a very light color, and use *Density* to control it
3. Use real units for light intensity (lumens). Related answer: [Simulating a 40W Light Bulb](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/180507/78972).

<sup>Lights: 10 million lumens (a really strong searchlight), Density: 0.1, Samples: 2000 + Denoiser</sup>
[image]

[image]

Comment: Adding a tiny bit of displacement in comp might help as well.