# Godrays through tiny cracks

Tags: volumetrics

I want to have godrays going through some tiny cracks in a shattered object.

It is a cube that is hollow inside (through a solidify modifier) and then has a cell fracture applied to it with the individual cells scaled down a bit. I placed a point lamp inside and added a cube with volume scatter around it but i am getting no godrays. I am fine if they are faked.

I heard about such things as bidir path tracing making it so light can more easily pass through tiny cracks but sadly this isn't in cycles. Luxcore does have bidir path tracing thought but it doesn't seem to have a 3.0 release, not even in their automatic builds (they are 2.93 as stated on their download page).

Blend File will be attached.

[image: Current State]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). You're connecting your *Volume* shader into a *Surface* socket. That's why you don't see any changes. BTW: Principled Volume shader [might be easier to work with](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/217652/78972).

Comment: hey yeah, sorry forgot to do that lol. was changing something around but it wasnt working before either. i will attach an update picture

Edit: I can get godrays now btw but i need to set my lamp to something absurdly high even at like 1mm lamp size. like 4000W and this scene is not huge. the inner cube there is like 1m big and my scatter ammount is at something like 0.15

Comment: Hi :). Don't worry about absurd light values, and also increase the light size. In *Principled Volume* a density of ~0,15 is like a muddy water. To simulate fog, you need ~0,03.

Comment: That said, you can also fake god rays in compositor which might be easier https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/sun_beams.html

Comment: Thank you guys!